# Setting values for inherited properties that are objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

Hi guys I have a question. So I have this class Sprite which basically holds basic information like position, etc.. Now it has an object property

```
this.pos = {x: 0, y: 0}
```

I also then have something that inherits from it, which is a Ball class. Now, everytime I call new Ball(px, py), it instantiates a ball at the proper location however it also moves EVERY ball instantiated before it to that same position.

The code inside Ball is:

```
this.pos.x = px;
this.pos.y = py;
```

I didn't know that this was the culprit until I changed it to:

```
this.pos = {x: px, y: py};
```

in which case it worked wonderfully. Now I'm just confused as to why the latter worked and not the former as for me it should have done the same thing.

Comment: Can we see how you defined your objects?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up, all of your objects are sharing the same position object, so it follows that they would change whenever you change that object. When you declare a new object with the `{}` literal, it creates a new, separate object, which you can change without affecting the other objects.

Since you refer to your objects as classes, I assume you're coming from a language that does things differently than Javascript. Though there are libraries that will create a more classlike structure, I recommend you read a bit about how inheritance works in Javascript. You should find these MDN article on [inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and [creating objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects) especially helpful!